# Can "tout" mean "most" instead of "all"?

Tags: vocabulaire

In [this](https://youtu.be/n7Pizs98NZg?t=113) youtube video in French at 1:53, the French subtitles say:

> Ce qui ne l'empêche pas d'être de **toutes** les manifestations qui dénoncent la brutalité policière.

while the English subtitles (not auto-translated, but instead presumably created by the uploader) say:

> Which doesn’t change the fact that he takes part in **many** protests against police brutality.

A quick DeepL translation of the French subtitle gives "all", and a quick WordReference glance for "tout" doesn't produce any entry with the meaning of "many".

Is the English subtitle translation inaccurate, or can "tout" really mean "many"? If "tout" can mean "many", can you give other example sentences; and how do I know when it means "all" vs when it means "many"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, “*tout*” means “all”. An accurate translation of “*être de toutes les manifestations …*” would be “take part in every protest …”.

“All” is obviously an exaggeration: at the very least, he presumably only took part in protests that took place in or around his home town. For whatever reason, the translator chose an inaccurate translation.